# Scheduled task after 24 Computer Uptime

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to setup a scheduled task which runs a PowerShell script after 24 hours of Computer uptime, but i cant find any trigger for it in the assistant.

Is there any way to realize this scheduled task?

Comment: Not quite you want to but near enough. In the System event log there's an event with ID 6013. It's logged at 12:00 of every day with information about a system uptime. You can bind a scheduler task to it.

Answer (score 2):

Use the 'At startup' trigger and delay it for 24 hours. If desired set repeat options.

[image]